# I can't use property inside of class method

Tags: php, oop

I want to check my request they have csrf token or not. So I created couple class for the checking this.

in my first class, I check the request and get the token

```
protected $token;

public function __construct($token){
 $this->token = $token;
 $this->checkToken();
}

protected function checkToken() {

    if (current_method() == "POST" || "PUT" || "PATCH") {
        if (CSRF::verifyToken(@$_POST['token'])) {
            $this->checkPrefix();
          }
     } elseif (current_method() == "GET" || "DELETE") {
        if (CSRF::verifyToken($this->token)) {
            $this->checkPrefix();
          }
      }
}
```

then I check request with the CSRF class. Problem is, I can't use `$this->token` inside of `checkToken()` method, it says null, but when I var_dump within __construct it gives me token as well..

Why this hapennig ? And how can I fix this ? I tried to pass $token as parameter with checkToken() method but I got same result..

Comment: yes, but it's happening in the class, I should able to use property in class method

Comment: Both of your IF statements are wrong

Comment: For me this is working fine:

<?php
class Test {
    protected $token;

    public function __construct($token) {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->checkToken();
    }

    protected function checkToken() {
        echo $this->token;
    }
}

$test = new Test('asdf');

and btw your IF statements are wrong..

Comment: @JohnConde what do you mean ?

Comment: thats not valid php, either `if (in_array(current_method(),array('POST,'PUT','PATCH')){...` or `if (current_method() == "POST" || current_method() =="PUT" || current_method() == "PATCH") {`

Comment: @smith I'm new at programming so.. I'm trying to learn step by step, in fact with baby steps :)

Comment: @Elliot make sure the issue isn't with the IF statements as mentioned by @smith because I get `$this->token;` correctly.

Comment: @Zeus Yeah I know , I guess they just say that this is not the way of using if statement, it may cause kind of exceptions of performance issues..

Comment: " it may cause kind of exceptions of performance issues" what may? your syntax is simply wrong .. so you have to do it another way (no option here)

Comment: @smith as I said, I'm new at programming sir, I'm not capable of answer this question.. But it's obvious there is something wrong in my code, and that causes above error

Comment: not sure the point of the above comment then, have you actually tried the suggested code? did it work? did it not work? ...

Comment: @smith yes it works, John Conde was right, there was a problem about my if statements..

Comment: well im answering, do what you like with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not with the variable, but with the if() syntax simply being wrong.

you have 2 options, i strongly suggest the first:

```
if (in_array(current_method(),array('POST,'PUT','PATCH')){
```

or

```
 if (current_method() == "POST" || current_method() =="PUT" || current_method() == "PATCH") {
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by smith, your syntax is wrong. See modified version of your code below.

Also, a little thing about good coding practices, your `current_method()` function is unclear and could be using reasonable amount of resources (maybe or maybe not) but in such situations it is always better to call such functions once and stored the returning value in a variable

```
protected function checkToken()
{
    $currentMethod = current_method();
    if (in_array($currentMethod, ["POST", "PUT", "PATCH"])) {
        if (CSRF::verifyToken(@$_POST['token'])) {
            $this->checkPrefix();
        }
    } elseif (in_array($currentMethod, ["GET", "DELETE"])) {
        if (CSRF::verifyToken($this->token)) {
            $this->checkPrefix();
        }
    }
}
```

You might just as well use `switch` block for these:

```
protected function checkToken()
{
    $currentMethod = current_method();
    switch ($currentMethod) {
        case "POST":
        case "PUT":
        case "PATCH":
            if (CSRF::verifyToken(@$_POST['token'])) {
                $this->checkPrefix();
            }
            break;
        case "GET":
        case "DELETE":
            if (CSRF::verifyToken($this->token)) {
                $this->checkPrefix();
            }
            break;
        default:
            // may be something else?
    }
}
```